# QtでQMediaPlayerが使えない

Tags: qt

環境：
Qt version 15 （[オンラインインストーラ](https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer?hsCtaTracking=99d9dd4f-5681-48d2-b096-470725510d34%7C074ddad0-fdef-4e53-8aa8-5e8a876d6ab4)を用いて、インストール）
OS Fedora

QMediaPlayerクラスを使用したく、.proファイルに
`QT += multimedia`
を記述後、headerファイルに
`#include <QMediaPlayer>`
を追加しました。しかし実行しても
`error: Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: multimedia`
と表示されてしまいます。
Qtのドキュメント([QMediaPlayer Class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html))を見ても、どこからQMediaPlayerをインストールすれば良いのかが記載されておらず、困っております。

どのようにすれば、ファイルの実行ができるようになるでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to install submodule Qtmultimedia on Fedora?](https://forum.qt.io/topic/127250/how-to-install-submodule-qtmultimedia-on-fedora)
こちらを参考に解決しました。

Answer (score 1):

英語版のStack Overflowに、同じ問題に対する解決策がいくつか提示されています。

- [makefile - Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: multimedia - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948466/project-error-unknown-modules-in-qt-multimedia)

こういった問題は、たいてい他の人も遭遇していて、エラーメッセージの全文または一部をGoogle検索にかけるとすぐに対策が見つかることが多いので、まずは検索してみることを推奨します。
また、日本語と英語では情報量が圧倒的に違うので、日本語よりも英語の情報を優先的に探すほうが正解に近づくことが多いです。

- [エラーメッセージの読み方と対処, 検索や質問の原則 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/cannorin/items/eb062aae88bfe2ad6fe5#google-%E6%A4%9C%E7%B4%A2%E3%81%AE%E5%A4%A7%E5%8E%9F%E5%89%87)

Comment: 参考URLのご提示ありがとうございます。[Building Qt 5 from Git](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git#Getting_the_source_code)や[Qt のソースコードを取得してビルドをする方法について](https://qiita.com/task_jp/items/f0753c52c86a26928465)等を参考にして取り組んでいたのですが、エラーが発生したり止まったりと苦戦していたところです。ご提示していただいた英語版の方も行ってみたいと思います。ありがとうございます。